# C# within a string of element how to Grond Group of Elements and arrange them in Sequence

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i Have String Like "A1-4,A1-6,A1-8,B1-1,B1-2,B1-3,B1-4...B1-8"
Here i Need to Arrange **A1** Element as **A1-1,A1-2,A1-3**  Beacause of i have 3 elements.
if i have elements Like A1-2,A1-3,A1-7,A1-8  I need to Arrange as **A1-1,A1-2,A1-3,A1-4** Beacause i have 4 element

Like This i need to Identify Type(A1 or A2 or B1 or Z1) arrange them according to that digits separated By comma.

```
string _sequenceNum="A1-4,A1-6,A1-8,B1-1,B1-2,B1-3,B1-4...B1-8";
_sequenceNum.split(",");
```

Here my Question is How to Identify Category

Please Help me

Comment: What does "Grond" in your title mean? Is the "..." in your code meant as it is written? If your question is not specific to C# version 3.0, you should remove the tag "c#-3.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to group and process your list:

```
string sequenceNum="A1-4,A1-6,A1-8,B1-1,B1-2,B1-3,B1-4,B1-8";
var sequence = sequenceNum.Split(",");

var newSequence = sequence
  .Select(x => x.Split('-')) // 1
  .GroupBy(x => x[0])        // 2
  .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, x.Count()).Select(i => x.Key + "-" + i)) // 3
  .ToList();                 // 4
```

In detail:

1. This splits e.g. "A1-4" into the array { "A1", "4" }
2. This groups the resulting sequence of arrays by their first element (e.g. "A1")
3. This uses `Enumerable.Range(1, x.Count())` to create a sequence 1, 2, ... (as much as there are elements in each group), then creates the new strings as "(groupname)-(index)". The `SelectMany` flattens the result into a single sequence.
4. Make a new list from the processed sequence

Answer (score 0):

```
   string _sequenceNum = "A1-4,B1-8,B1-3,B1-1,A1-8,B1-4,A1-6,B1-2";         
            var test = _sequenceNum.Split(',');           
              Array.Sort(test);        
             foreach (var a in test)         
                 Console.WriteLine(a);        
             foreach (var a in test.Where(i => i.StartsWith("A")))         
                 Console.WriteLine(a);  
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",test));        
             Console.ReadLine();
```